# Fetch all stargazers over time of a repository

Tags: python, api, github

I’m trying to fetch the timestamp of all the starred_at for every stargazer via GitHub REST API.

I’m passing in the following request:

```
headers={‘Accept’: ‘application/vnd.github.v3.star+json’}
url = "https://api.github.com/repos/tensorflow/tensorflow/stargazers?per_page=100"
response = requests.get(url,headers=headers)
```

But on the [TensorFlow GitHub](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow) repository website, the total stargazers count is 159k, whereas the ones fetched from REST API total count is 40K.

Am I missing any other query parameters to fetch the remaining 119k stargazers?

Comment: I just hit the request once. Then use the headers → links to check the number of items(stargazers) I can get. In my case it’s:
https://api.github.com/repositories/45717250/stargazers?per_page=100&page=2; rel=“next”, https://api.github.com/repositories/45717250/stargazers?per_page=100&page=400; rel=“last”

So that’s 100 items per page and 400 pages in total. We get 40k items. Whereas the actual count is ~160k

Comment: Checked with other repositories which have over 40000+ stargazers. Sadly it’s the same. They all stop at page=400.

https://api.github.com/repos/vuejs/vue/stargazers?per_page=100
https://api.github.com/repos/freecodecamp/freecodecamp/stargazers?per_page=100 

These respectively have 187k and 329k stargazers.